# Yahoo - "Uh oh - we can't recover your account online because there are no other options on file for your account."

Tags: yahoo-mail

Question is as in title.

I'm not trying to recover my account at all.  I'm just trying to sign in to my yahoo mail account, and whenever I enter the email address and press enter, I get the above error message.  I need access to my emails now and don't understand how to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have exhausted your online recovery options, you must call Yahoo Telephone Support which is difficult to do

https://subscriptions.yahoo.com/products/yahoo-account-pro-help?